# How to unit test Silverlight 3 Out-Of-Browser application?

Tags: silverlight, unit-testing

How to unit test Silverlight 3 Out-Of-Browser application?

Answer (score 2):

Roy Osherove has created an open source framework to test silverlight controls 
It called [SilverUnit](http://cthru.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SilverUnit%20examples) and it uses Typemock in order to intercept .NET calls and fake their behaviour.

SilverUnit lets you test your controls using simple unit testing framework no browser required.

Seems like a good solution for what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since you  are into beta stuff (Silverlight 3), are you willing to consider using VS 2010?
If so, take a look at Mathew Aniyan's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/mathew_aniyan/). He has lots of information on data driven Coded UI Tests.